# How to import and register class from a list of service providers at runtime?

Tags: php, laravel, psr-4

Are you able to solve this problem? help me

**Procedure**

- There is a folder called 'plugins' in the base path of laravel;
- Inside that folder there are only subfolders that are the plugins;
- In the subfolder where the plugin is, there is a single file to be imported called PluginNameServiceProvider.php;
- The PluginNameServiceProvider.php in turn will be registered by a main service provider, let's say MainServiceProvider.php, but for that, the PluginNameServiceProvider class must be available/accessible for use;

**Problem**

- The user loads the subfolder containing the 'plugin' in 'zip' format through a GUI, then the system extracts the loaded 'zip' file and directs it to the appropriate location, no similar file exists before that;
- When the 'composer update or composer dump-autoload' command is executed the PluginNameServiceProvider class is resolved and can be used elsewhere, but not before that;
- The aforementioned composer commands are executed at fixed times, however, the PluginNameServiceProvider class must be available immediately, not being able to depend on composer under penalty of preventing the use of the plugin;

**What was tried**

A temporary autoloader was created that searches for classes not yet resolved by composer as below, however, it is not working

```
 try{ 
 
 /**
 * For information on 'spl_autoload_register' see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php
 * For information on 'glob()' see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php
 * For information on 'app()' see: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-app
 * base_path() returns the path of the plugins folder, something like: 'D:\www\laravel\plguins'
 * $name returns the namespace of the plugin's service provider, something like: '\plugins\plugin-name\Providers\PluginNameServiceProvider'
 * 'File::' is an abbreviation for the facade 'Illuminate\support\facades\File'
 **/

 //Import file if class not found
 spl_autoload_register(function ($name) {
    //Check if the file exists before importing it
    if(File::exists(base_path($name). '.php')){
    include(base_path($name). '.php');
    }
 });

 //Access the plugins folder and list the directories
 $folders = File::directories(base_path('plugins'));

 //Iterates over a set of subfolders and accesses each one of them looking for a file with 'Provider.php' in the name
 foreach($folders as $item){
    //Returns the absolute path of the first service provider it finds
    $str = collect(glob(base_path('plugins'). "\\". $item . '\\Providers\\*Provider.php'))->first();
    
    //Proceed with registration if the plugin has a service provider, otherwise continue the loop
    if(!is_null($str)){

    //Prepare the class name and namespace to be used
    $filter = pathinfo($str);
    $path = $filter['dirname'] .'\\'. $filter['filename'];
    $newclass = str_replace('.php', '', strstr($str, '\plugins'));
    
    //Register the plugin provider
    app()->register(new $newclass(app()));
    }
 }  
} catch(\Exception $e){
    dd($e->getMessage());
}
```

The problem with my code is that it is not registering the service providers whose namespace has not yet been mapped by the composer. The problem seems to be in spl_autoload_register, I say it seems because the code is in a place that 'kills' laravel in case of a fatal error so the debug options are minimal and the code cannot be moved to another place as it is included inside a package.

**Current behavior**

The service provider seems to have been imported due to the fact that 'include()' returns 1, however, there are two types of situations: 1) It gives the error 'class not found'; 2) It doesn't display any errors and it doesn't execute the service provider code either.

**Expected behavior**

The code must import the service provider and register it, so that the code present in that service provider is executed.

**Plugin service provider example to be registered**

```
<?php
namespace plugins\plugin-name\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class PluginNameServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
    dd(['status' => 'Registered!', 'more' => app()]);
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
    //
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoever gives a negative vote should present their justifications.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the modification below:

**Before**

```
//Returns the absolute path of the first service provider it finds
$str = collect(glob(base_path('plugins'). "\\". $item . '\\Providers\\*Provider.php'))->first();
```

**After**

```
 //Returns the absolute path of the first service provider it finds
 $str = collect(glob($item . '\\Providers\\*Provider.php'))->first();
```

I'll leave the code there in the question in case someone tries to implement a hook functionality in php and has a similar problem. If you use it, be kind and give proper credit.